# Colors are Not Printed Properly using SLDS in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, css, lightning-design-system

I have a Visualforce page styled using SLDS elements. I am facing an issue with colors not being visible when we are printing the HTML page. I believe this may be caused due to print styles being applied by the Lightning Design System (I am referring to the CSS media print queries).

**Is there any way to print colors by overriding the CSS media print query, or do we need to create our own custom CSS for printing the page?**

Here is a sample of the standard data table markup:

```
<div class="slds-scope">
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
    <thead>
      <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Opportunity Name</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Close Date</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Stage</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Confidence">Confidence</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Amount">Amount</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Contact">Contact</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" data-label="Opportunity Name">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Cloudhub</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">Cloudhub</div>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color : green" data-label="Close Date">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Prospecting">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Prospecting">Prospecting</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Confidence">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="20%">20%</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Amount">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="$25k">$25k</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Contact">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="jrogers@cloudhub.com">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">jrogers@cloudhub.com</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" data-label="Opportunity Name">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub + Anypoint Connectors">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Cloudhub + Anypoint Connectors</a>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">Cloudhub</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Close Date">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Prospecting">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Prospecting">Prospecting</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Confidence">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="20%">20%</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Amount">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="$25k">$25k</div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Contact">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="jrogers@cloudhub.com">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">jrogers@cloudhub.com</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I facing the issue specifically on this markup:

```
<td style="background-color : green" data-label="Close Date">
   <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
</td>
```

For this example, I have only one cell colored. Practically, we may have many cells with different colors.

In order to replicate the issue, one can click Ctrl + p to open the print preview dialog.

Comment: Can you post an example of your code that isn't showing colors properly?

Comment: I am using the standard data table markup from the lightning design documentation. I have added the markup.

Comment: Did I miss it? I don't see any color CSS or classes that would even show color but on mobile so. Can you outline the lines u have issue with and a screenshot as well

Comment: Name space your datatable CSS

Answer (score 1):

On Visualforce pages, if you use the [`apex:slds`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm) component, the resulting [Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/) (SLDS) stylesheet applies the following styles to the document via the [`@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) query:

```
@media print {
    .slds-scope *,
    .slds-scope *:before,
    .slds-scope *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property is set to `transparent` when printing and uses the [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) rule to override any other declarations.

You can override this default styling by incorporating the [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) rule in your own custom CSS (place this after the [`apex:slds`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm) component on your Visualforce page to ensure [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is calculated according to your wishes):

```
@media print {
    .slds-scope td {
        background-color: green !important;
    }
}
```

Lastly, make sure you enable Background Graphics in your browser's printer settings, as many of the print settings are outside of the realm of CSS and at the browser level:

[image]